# How to remove each element from ng-repeat with a specific timeout

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

How to remove the values from the ng-repeat array with a timeout from when they are added.

```
$timeout(function() {
     $scope.datas.splice($scope.datas[$scope.datas.length - 1]) // just something
}, 4000);
```

What I needed is.

 If I add an element to that array only that element has to be removed after the timeout specified. not the last added element. So each element will have their own timeout

Here is a plunker for some help. https://plnkr.co/edit/5TtcwRqiXGeAOddn5wPF?p=preview.

I have no clue how to achieve that. A Little help needed.

Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean ? You are using push() to add elements, which adds to the last. Which element do you want to remove then

Comment: if there is a timeout of 4 seconds. items which are added 4 seconds ago should be removed @DeveshSati

Comment: the way you are asking will need to add a timestamp with each added item and then based on time difference you need to remove the element

Comment: If you use push to add then use pop to remove, if you use unshift then use shift to remove. if you replace an element in the array then store the index to splice the element.

Comment: more or less. it is similar. yes @Manish. something similar to timers in notification

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a timeout in your **addValue** function. Inside of this timeout you get the index of the added element and you remove it like this :

```
$scope.addValue = function() {
    var element = $scope.datas[$scope.datas.length - 1] + 1;
    $scope.datas.push(element);
    $timeout(function(){
        var index = $scope.datas.indexOf(element);
        $scope.datas.splice(index, 1)
    }, 2000);
};
```

[Here](https://plnkr.co/edit/iV9WYCLVCdqnpskA6wiJ?p=preview) is a working plunker

Comment: so there is a timeout set for each element that gets added to the array.

Comment: Yes after a new element is added a timeout is started and at the end of it the element is removed

Comment: that is not working always. try adding 10 or more elements simultaneously. only few elements gets removed

Comment: put timeout in separate function and call it passing the element

Comment: Why would you separate it in two functions ?

Comment: He is adding element simultaneously. The element value will get changed if it is called after 2s.

Comment: Hum i'm not sure to get what you mean, but try the plunker it's working even if you click quickly on the add button

Comment: @Rishi. it doesn't make any difference. the element won't change after added to the timeout as it is locally declared inside the timeout. it will be same I suppose

Comment: yeah. sorry I forgot